# React - How to format phone number as user types

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, validation, formatting

I need to format a 10 digit string to this format: '(123) 456-7890'.
However, I need this to happen as the user types. So if the user has inputted only 3 digits, the input should display: '(123)'.
If they've inputted 5 digits the input should display: '(123) 45'

With my current code, the formatting only takes place after the 10th character is entered. I'd like it so that it formats it from the third character onwards.

````
const phoneRegex = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/

const handleInput = (value) => {
  return (
    value.replace(phoneRegex, '($1) $2-$3')
  )
}

class FindASubscriber extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      value: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { label, placeholder, feedback } = this.props
    const { value} = this.state
    return (
      <div className="find__a__subscriber">
        <FlexGrid>
          <FlexGrid.Col>
            <FlexGrid.Row>
              <Input
                feedback={feedback}
                label={label}
                type="text"
                pattern="[0-9]*"
                placeholder={placeholder}
                value={handleInput(value)}
                maxLength="10"
                onChange={
                 (event) => this.setState({value: event.target.value})
                }
              />
            </FlexGrid.Row>
          </FlexGrid.Col>
        </FlexGrid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can `normalize` the `input` like so

- the `value` is up-to-date in relation to `event.target.value`
- `previousValue` is what has already been validated and set to `state`

This is structured in a way to prevent invalid characters from updating the input and also limits the input to 10 numbers.

**Click the `Run code snippet` button below for a working example.**

---

```
const normalizeInput = (value, previousValue) => {
  // return nothing if no value
  if (!value) return value; 

  // only allows 0-9 inputs
  const currentValue = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  const cvLength = currentValue.length; 

  if (!previousValue || value.length > previousValue.length) {

    // returns: "x", "xx", "xxx"
    if (cvLength < 4) return currentValue; 

    // returns: "(xxx)", "(xxx) x", "(xxx) xx", "(xxx) xxx",
    if (cvLength < 7) return `(${currentValue.slice(0, 3)}) ${currentValue.slice(3)}`; 

    // returns: "(xxx) xxx-", (xxx) xxx-x", "(xxx) xxx-xx", "(xxx) xxx-xxx", "(xxx) xxx-xxxx"
    return `(${currentValue.slice(0, 3)}) ${currentValue.slice(3, 6)}-${currentValue.slice(6, 10)}`; 
  }
};
```

```js
const normalizeInput = (value, previousValue) => {
  if (!value) return value;
  const currentValue = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  const cvLength = currentValue.length;
  
  if (!previousValue || value.length > previousValue.length) {
    if (cvLength < 4) return currentValue;
    if (cvLength < 7) return `(${currentValue.slice(0, 3)}) ${currentValue.slice(3)}`;
    return `(${currentValue.slice(0, 3)}) ${currentValue.slice(3, 6)}-${currentValue.slice(6, 10)}`;
  }
};

const validateInput = value => {
  let error = ""
  
  if (!value) error = "Required!"
  else if (value.length !== 14) error = "Invalid phone format. ex: (555) 555-5555";
  
  return error;
};
    
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = { phone: "", error: "" };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChange({ target: { value } }) {   
    this.setState(prevState=> ({ phone: normalizeInput(value, prevState.phone) }));
  };
  
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const error = validateInput(this.state.phone);
    
    this.setState({ error }, () => {
       if(!error) {
         setTimeout(() => {
           alert(JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 4));
         }, 300)
       }
    });
  }
  
  handleReset() {
     this.setState({ phone: "", error: "" });
  };
  
  render() {
    return(
      <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="input-container">
          <p className="label">Phone:</p>
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            name="phone"
            placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx"
            value={this.state.phone}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          {this.state.error && <p className="error">{this.state.error}</p>}
        </div>
        <div className="btn-container">
          <button 
             className="btn danger"
             type="button"
             onClick={this.handleReset}
           >
            Reset
          </button>
          <button className="btn primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
html {
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  transition-property: color,background-color,border-color;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.form {
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.danger {
  background-color: #f0506e;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
 
.danger:hover {
  background-color: #ee395b;
  color: #fff;
}

.error {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -20px;
  padding-left: 26%;
  color: red;
  text-align: left;
}

.input {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  transition-property: color,background-color,border;
 }

.input-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.label {
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 34px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
}

.primary {
  background-color: #1e87f0;
}

.primary:hover {
  background-color: #0f7ae5;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id='root'>
</div>
```

---

Or... have 3 separate inputs and combine them when done.

```js
const validateInput = value => {
  let error = ""
  
  if (!value) error = "Required!"
  else if (value.length !== 14) error = "Invalid phone format. ex: (555) 555-5555";
  
  return error;
};

const initialState = {
 areaCode: "",
 prefix: "",
 suffix: "",
 error: ""
};
    
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = initialState;
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
    this.setInputRef = this.setInputRef.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChange({ target: { name, value } }) {
    let valueChanged = false;
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const nextValue = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
      const changedValue = prevState[name];
      if (changedValue.length !== nextValue.length) valueChanged = true;
  
      return { [name]: nextValue }
    }, () => {
      if(valueChanged) this.handleFocus(name)
    });
  };
  
  setInputRef(name, element) {
   this[name] = element;
  }
  
  handleFocus(name){
    const { areaCode, prefix, suffix } = this.state;
    const areaCodeFilled = areaCode.length === 3;
    const prefixFilled = prefix.length === 3;

    if(areaCodeFilled && name === "areaCode") {
      this.prefix.focus();
      this.prefix.selectionEnd = 0;
    } else if(prefixFilled && name === "prefix") {
      this.suffix.focus();
      this.suffix.selectionEnd = 0;
    }
  }
  
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { areaCode, prefix, suffix } = this.state;
    const phoneNumber = `(${areaCode}) ${prefix}-${suffix}`
    const error = validateInput(phoneNumber);
    
    this.setState({ error }, () => {
       if(!error) {
         setTimeout(() => {
           alert(phoneNumber);
         }, 300)
       }
    });
  }
  
  handleReset() {
     this.setState(initialState);
  };
  
  render() {
    return(
      <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="input-container">
          <div className="label">
            Phone:
          </div>
          <div className="parenthesis" style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 2}}>&#40;</div>
          <input
            className="input area-code"
            type="text"
            name="areaCode"
            placeholder="xxx"
            value={this.state.areaCode}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            maxLength="3"
          />
           <div className="parenthesis" style={{ marginRight: 2}}>&#41;</div>
          <input
            ref={node => this.setInputRef("prefix", node)}
            className="input prefix"
            type="text"
            name="prefix"
            placeholder="xxx"
            value={this.state.prefix}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            maxLength="3"
          />
          <div className="dash">-</div>
          <input
            ref={node => this.setInputRef("suffix", node)}
            className="input suffix"
            type="text"
            name="suffix"
            placeholder="xxxx"
            value={this.state.suffix}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            maxLength="4"
          />
        </div>
         <p className="error">{this.state.error}</p>
        <div className="btn-container">
          <button 
             className="btn danger"
             type="button"
             onClick={this.handleReset}
           >
            Reset
          </button>
          <button className="btn primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
html {
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  transition-property: color,background-color,border-color;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.form {
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.danger {
  background-color: #f0506e;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
 
.danger:hover {
  background-color: #ee395b;
  color: #fff;
}

.error {
  margin: 0;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  padding-left: 26%;
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
}

.input {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 0 3px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
}
 
.area-code,.prefix {
 width: 27px;
}

.suffix {
 width: 38px;
}

.dash,.parenthesis {
 display: flex;
}

.input-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;

    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  transition-property: color,background-color,borde
}

.label {
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 8px;
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 34px;
}

.primary {
  background-color: #1e87f0;
}

.primary:hover {
  background-color: #0f7ae5;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id='root'>
</div>
```

Comment: I found this solution while I was looking for an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61240217/how-to-stop-cursor-from-jumping-to-the-end-of-input. I think your solution also has the issue that I am facing which is "cursor jumping to the end of input when you edit somewhere in the middle of the string".

Comment: While I understand what you're trying to accomplish, unfortunately with this solution it's not possible (since it's slicing up the value based upon its length). Instead, you might want to consider breaking the input into 3 inputs: filling out the area code: "123", and then once it's been filled, focus the cursor on the next input: "567", and once it's been filled, focusing the cursor on the last four digits: "8910". Each is an independent input, but to the user, it appears formatted as one input. Then, changing one wouldn't affect the other since they are separate inputs with separate values.

Comment: Updated example above to include 3 separate inputs. Not perfect, but it essentially does the same thing. You can also get rid of the auto focus on inputs based upon value change and instead have the user tab through them.

Comment: Matt- That is a nice way of resolving this issue. My problem however will be that I get input field's name, id from the backend in JSON response. And when I submit the form, backend expects me to submit the phone value as one input field allocated to the name that it sent in the first place.

Comment: I don't see a problem. When you retrieve it from the back end, you can save it to the component's state accordingly... first 3 digits: area code, next 3: prefix, and next 4 suffix. Manipulate the state as needed using the inputs, then when submitting, before sending it to the backend, put them back together (like the second example does in the onSubmit function) and then send it back as the same name field with the same id.

Comment: @MattCarlotta Your second solution is the exact one that I was looking for, but the only problem is that the user needs to be educated about tabbing through it.

Comment: @MattCarlotta can you give me same example in react native ?

Answer (score 5):

It's all about formatting. Any key that prints a character
should cause a rewrite of the input field.
This way the user only sees valid formatted field, no matter what he does.

The regex is simple  `^\D*(\d{0,3})\D*(\d{0,3})\D*(\d{0,4})`

```js
function getFormattedPhoneNum( input ) {
  let output = "(";
  input.replace( /^\D*(\d{0,3})\D*(\d{0,3})\D*(\d{0,4})/, function( match, g1, g2, g3 )
      {
        if ( g1.length ) {
          output += g1;
          if ( g1.length == 3 ) {
              output += ")";
              if ( g2.length ) {
                  output += " " + g2; 
                  if ( g2.length == 3 ) {
                      output += " - ";
                      if ( g3.length ) {
                          output += g3;
                      }
                  }
              }
           }
        }
      }       
    );        
  return output;
 }       

console.log( getFormattedPhoneNum("") );
console.log( getFormattedPhoneNum("2") );
console.log( getFormattedPhoneNum("asdf20as3d") );
console.log( getFormattedPhoneNum("203") );
console.log( getFormattedPhoneNum("203-44") );
console.log( getFormattedPhoneNum("444sg52asdf22fd44gs") );
console.log( getFormattedPhoneNum("444sg526sdf22fd44gs") );
console.log( getFormattedPhoneNum("444sg526sdf2244gs") );
console.log( getFormattedPhoneNum(" ra098 848 73653k-atui ") );
```

You could even get fancier and show underscores where a character
should be at any given time.
Like
`(___) ___ - ____`
`(20_) ___ - ____`
`(123) 456 - ____`

etc... (let me know if you want this)

Comment: Amazing answer, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: What if the operator code in some countries has 2 digits. How do I cover all the cases?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code's regex only matches when ten digits are entered (3, 3, then 4). You could update the regex to accept a range of digits, such as:

```
^\(?([0-9]{0,3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{0,3})[-. ]?([0-9]{0,4})$
```

Or you could have the regex simply make sure that 0-10 digits are entered ([0-9]{0,10}) and then split the string yourself into substrings of length 3, 3, and 4. Doing it the latter way seems better since you only want to show certain characters depending on how many digits the user has entered:

> 1 -> (1
>
> 123 -> (123)
>
> 1234567 -> (123) 456-7
>
> 1234567890 -> (123) 456-7890

You would have to handle each of these cases which a simple replace won't do.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js it has a AsYouType function, that you can use on your inputs

Answer (score 0):

perhaps, something as the following will work for someone:

```
   onChange={(e) => {
                if (e.target.value.length < 13) {
                  var cleaned = ("" + e.target.value).replace(/\D/g, "");

                  let normValue = `${cleaned.substring(0, 3)}${
                    cleaned.length > 3 ? "-" : ""
                  }${cleaned.substring(3, 6)}${
                    cleaned.length > 6 ? "-" : ""
                  }${cleaned.substring(6, 11)}`;

                  handleChange(normValue);
                }
              }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-formatter
this input component formats number and returns just number.

[image]